# What does a member status value of "2" mean on a SharePoint Community site?

Tags: 2013, community-site

When users click "Join this Community" on a SharePoint 2013 community site, it automatically adds their name to the members list with a **Member Status** value of **1**. Their reputation score starts at zero, until they contribute to the discussion board.

However, we have a handful of users with a **Member Status** value of **2**. These users also always have a **Reputation Score = -1**.

What is the difference between a member status of 1 and of 2? What do they mean?

Comment: what's unique about those user, are the active user in communities? are the still part of communities? usually when a user left the community then its reputation become negative.

Comment: I'm not sure what makes them unique. We only just started the community, so it's possible they joined and then left immediately. Is this what happens when a user leaves? Their status changes from 1 to 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user join the community then its Member Status **set to 1** with reputation score of 0.

But if the user left the community without doing anything then his Member status change from **1 to 2** and reputation **goes to Minus -1**

I.e if User a join and left without any participation then his Member Status will **2** & Reputation Score will be **-1**

If user b join the community and responde couple of post, lets say its reputation score is 10...if he left the community then His Member Status **will be 2** and Reputation score **will be -11**